# Can we extract the contents of !DOCTYPE declaration using XPATH?

Tags: doctype, xpath-2.0

I have the below sample XML from which I want to extract the DOCTYPE using Xpath. Is this possible?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE note SYSTEM "Note.dtd">
<note>
<to>Tove</to>
<from>Jani</from>
<heading>Reminder</heading>
<body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
```

As far as I have read, Xpath will work only on elements and attributes and not on the prolog / doctype, just wanted to confirm that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand Xpath, it works on a node tree representing the xml, but isn't xml in itself. The node tree will always have the root element as the first node, excluded be the document root. So in your example, "note" will be something to act upon. Everything prior to this node gets tossed when parsing the xml.

So no, the doctype wont be reachable with xpath.

Comment: You are right that the doctype can't be read with Xpath, but not everything prior to the root node gets tossed. You can't read

Comment: Was too slow in my initial comment: You are right that the doctype can't be read with Xpath, but not everything prior to the root node gets tossed. You can't read doctype and xml declaration, but you can read comments and processing-instructions that occur prior to the root node. Doesn't help here, just a clarification.